# Text file searching - find and process parse lines 'near' a matched result

Tags: file, full-text-search, text-editor, text-parsing

Constantly having to parse text log files.  These are typically application and http logs.  These logfiles contain myriad information and searching can be like the proverbial needle in a haystack.

Typically text editors such as BBEdit are fine when using regexes and some of it's line extraction/deletion features.  Although this finds or extracts individual items or lines,  it won't help with context where it would be really useful to extract the item's row plus the previous and subsequent few rows.

Consider the following source text -- obviously not a logfile!

```
01 Lorem ipsum sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
02 Pellentesque eu est ac neque gravida consectetur id non sem.
00 Nullam in tortor vulputate, porttitor mauris et, tristique justo.
03 Suspendisse ac lorem molestie, faucibus tortor sed, euismod elit.
04 Sed auctor leo non dolor pharetra, eu faucibus felis bibendum.
05 Integer id turpis ullamcorper magna venenatis ultrices.
06 Mauris semper nulla et lorem dignissim sollicitudin.
07 Curabitur fringilla turpis a justo sodales efficitur.
08 Phasellus dictum erat et mi euismod, ut ultricies augue molestie.
09 Quisque eget arcu ut ligula aliquam viverra vitae nec felis.
10 Maecenas nec dolor orci ac elit eleifend elementum.
11 Nullam ut lacus in sem fringilla suscipit.
12 Suspendisse sollicitudin massa fermentum magna dapibus bibendum.
13 Maecenas vestibulum libero id tortor molestie condimentum.
```

It's easy to search for all the lines containing "dolor" with a text editor:

```
04 Sed auctor leo non dolor pharetra, eu faucibus felis bibendum.
10 Maecenas nec dolor orci ac elit eleifend elementum.
```

What I really want is to find the:

- target line plus the previous and subsequent 2 or 3 lines;
- target line and then look around it for lines containing `xyz` and return this line through to the target line
- target line then apply some other filter
- the target line,  backtracking to some previous text,  then process the subsequent x lines using some regexes

**Question:**  what are the best programmer tools to do this?  Awk?  Python? Grep  Some other specialist tools?  Particularly interested in Mac tools,  but Windows tools could work.

Comment: You can use `grep` with the `-C` option to display a given number of lines before and after a match

Comment: Is there a better StackOverflow site to ask this kind of question?

Answer (score 1):

On the Unix (Linux or Mac) command line, you can use `grep` with the -C option to display a given number of lines before and after a match. For example (where `test.txt` is your example text):

```
$ grep -C 1 dolor test.txt
03 Suspendisse ac lorem molestie, faucibus tortor sed, euismod elit.
04 Sed auctor leo non dolor pharetra, eu faucibus felis bibendum.
05 Integer id turpis ullamcorper magna venenatis ultrices.
--
09 Quisque eget arcu ut ligula aliquam viverra vitae nec felis.
10 Maecenas nec dolor orci ac elit eleifend elementum.
11 Nullam ut lacus in sem fringilla suscipit.
```